# PostScript / DVI / PDF all-in-one viewer for Windows

Tags: windows, pdf-viewer, postscript

Is there a PS / DVI / PDF all-in-one viewer for Windows?

I thought GhostScript would be able to do this but I wasn't able to open DVI files. (Admittedly I have no understanding of these file formats.) But even trying to open a PostScript file with GhostScript, I can only seem to view the first page of any document. (Unless [the files themselves](http://www.math.ias.edu/QFT/fall/index.html) are corrupt or of an odd format?)

Gratis preferred, but paid considered.

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince). Unfortunately, I'm not sure about its capabilities when run on Windows. But it advertises itself as

> a document viewer for multiple document formats. [...] Evince is
>   specifically designed to support the file following formats: PDF,
>   Postscript, djvu, tiff, dvi, XPS, SyncTex support with gedit, comics
>   books (cbr,cbz,cb7 and cbt). For a comprehensive list of formats
>   supported, see [Supported Document Formats](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince/SupportedDocumentFormats).

And someone created [Windows binaries](http://portableapps.com/apps/office/evince_portable), albeit they seem to be little outdated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

DVI is an intermediate format when creating postscript files from latex source. You might want to consider installation of a complete latex distribution like miktex (http://miktex.org/), which includes all necessary viewers (i.e. in particular Yap for viewing dvi files)